# Special chars are replaces with a square in android app

Tags: android, character-encoding

In my android app I make a simple toast

```
Toast.makeText(
        parent.getApplicationContext(),
        parent.getResources().getIdentifier(result, "string",
        parent.getPackageName()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This

```
parent.getResources().getIdentifier(result, "string", parent.getPackageName())
```

retrieves a string whose name matches result from `strings.xml`. I have a strings.xml file for english and german language. The problem is that special chars in german language like Ü Ö Ä are not displayed correctly. They are replaced by a square symbol.

The strings.xml are utf-8 encoded.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do not use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know **exactly *why* you need it**. In this case, you most certainly do not need it. Please use `parent`, not `parent.getApplicationContext()`. I doubt that will solve your problem, but I would certainly start there, as the misuse of `Application` causes odd UI behavior.

Comment: The toast is performed in a class that extends AsyncTask and not activity. So parent is the activity that creates the task...

Comment: Which still means you should use `parent`, not `parent.getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Ok I changed that, but as you say the problem is still there.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised. Normally, the squares indicate missing glyphs in the font. However, if you are testing this on a fairly normal device or emulator, it definitely has glyphs for characters with umlauts in the `Droid` and `Ruboto` fonts. Hence, I'm not quite certain why you would be getting squares in this case.

Comment: Did you try
Toast.makeText(parent,parent.getRources().getString(result), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
?

Answer (score 2):

ArtWorkAD,

It appears as though your problem is being caused by the fact that the `Toast.makeText()` method is not using the correct Charset when pulling your special characters from the resources.

I suggest as a debugging step you pull the string down from the resources independantly and use the

```
Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration).show();
```

overload to render your text.  This way you can confirm that the text is what you expect and narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the android documentation carefully :
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

Comment: Not helpful at all for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Toast Message , you can use custom dialog in which you can have on TextView to show this string.Now use

```
    TextView textView=new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your string"));
```

Hope this work for you but have not tried